# add json array with object to Codable model in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode

I have json reponse from server which contains array with json object. How do i store it to my product modal.

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "image_galleries":[
        {"image_url":"8331663c9c5437a4f047ed45a56190a1-2-600x600.jpeg"},
        {"image_url":"31875021aa1f2a37f3192610223eb12b-3-600x600.jpeg"},
        {"image_url":"ac1312a66aa1bf8c34676a5d550c5e24-4-600x600.jpeg"},
        {"image_url":"5880621259e66151938a412e4197d8be-5-600x600.jpeg"}
    ],
    "id": "12345678"
}
```

My ProductModel

```
struct ProductModel: Codable{
    //var image_galleries: [String: [String?]]?
    var image_galleries: [String: [Array<String?>]]?
    var product_id: String?
}
```

Adding response object to my ProductModel

```
let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(ProductModel.self, from: response!)
self.Product = data
```

When i print the `image_galleries` it always return null

```
print("Images", self.Product?.image_galleries as Any) // will print nil
print("Id", self.Product?.product_id) // Will print 12345678
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using codable you don't need to do the `Array<String>` and stuff like that. You can simply make an another decodable and codable and achieve it.

```
struct ProductModel: Decodable{
    var image_galleries: [Galleries]
    let id: String
    let status: Int
}

struct Galleries: Decodable {
let image_url: String
}
```

Also, instead of writing `image_galleries`, you should use `imageGalleries` and when you are decoding, you can use `.convertFromSnakeCase`, it is a key decoding strategy as in `Swift` we follow camelCase instead of snake_case.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
do {

let json = try decode.decode(ProducModel.self, from: data) 
} catch let error {
 print(error)
}
```

Comment: instead of using `Decodable` in your example I used `Codable` and it still works, is there any difference?

Comment: Yes, Codable == Encodable & Decodable. Please do a google search, you will learn a lot.

Comment: Please one last thing, when I tried to use the `image_galleries as! Array`, I got `Cast from '[Galleries]?' to unrelated type 'Array<String>' always fails`

Comment: Why are you casting it as an `Array`, a `Decodable` and an `Array` are different structures and it is always going to fail. Please post a separate question if you are facing any other issues.